# Facebook graph, post action with extra parameters

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have created an application with their associated Open Graph actions. Got problem with submitting one action, which is using extra field "message". When admin or tester using this action it works fine, **but it is not working with facebook's  test users**, such is "Auth Dialog Preview User", it gives an error "Message: This action is not allowed to set a user message because this property was not requested for approval."  Why it gives this error to the test user? And when i submit this action, facebook replies me that they can not test this action... What i missed?

http://gyazo.com/42ebb0a5c12f3c47fed64f5eb9930f61

Comment: Did you manage to get this resolved eventually?  Or, your actions are still pending?

Answer (score 0):

> Why it gives this error to the test user?

Doesn’t it quiet clearly say so:

> "Message: This action is not allowed to set a user message because this property was not requested for approval."

…?

Users that are not admins can’t post actions that have not been approved by Facebook.

Comment: I dont know why. It is works to admin users. or users i setup as testers. but didnt to default test users...

Comment: Of course it works for admins, because they’re supposed to be able to test actions _before_ they are approved …

Comment: then why facebook can not test this action and approve it? did they use same test account to check, or msth else? they replied me "we can not test this action properly"

Answer (score 0):

I've been beating my head against the wall on this problem as well.

First: There is a Facebook Bug that is currently triaged on this topic.

[Facebook Bug Link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/331215723624086?browse=search_500dd01280b133317300421)

Second: I noticed Facebook has updated the description of the Message property.

> message: Allows users to write a personalized message attached to this
>   action. You can only use user message when the text is entered by the
>   user (not pre-populated). string

[Facebook page that details the Message parameter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/)

You'll notice it clearly states that it can't be pre-populated now. I don't remember it saying that previously (Of course my memory could be failing me) and I'm curious if that means even if the user composed the message on my application, Facebook considers the string I'm feeding the action pre-populated even though it's an actual unique comment written by the user. In other words you may have to use Facebook code (plugin, dialog, etc...) to prompt the user to actually enter a message attached to the action.

Third: FYI, I was able to get my action approved (With the Message parameter) but the same error persists for all users attempting to submit the action with the exception of admins and testers, so getting your action approved won't likely alleviate the issue. It's either an actual bug or a misunderstanding of the capabilities/functionality of the Message parameter.

Apologies for this being a partial answer slash extension to the question.